# 1px gap between divs in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am displaying a div with 2 divs in it. One div has a colored background. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but there appears a gap in Internet Explorer 11.

I don't see the gap always, it changes based on how far i am zoomed in. When i see it, and i zoom further, it can dissappear again.

Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  background: #000000;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  margin-left:50%;
  padding:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">hello</div>
</div>
```

And here is the gap that sometimes appears in IE11:
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving **box-sizing** property to your container

```
.container {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -o-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

It might be getting `box-sizing:content-box` inherited from somewhere on in your css.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This improves the situation, it shows gaps less often (based on different zoom-levels), however, it does not solve it completely. Sometimes a gap still occurs.

Comment: I too faced similar issue,